# Show Loading for axios Post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a Loading for my Axios Request

The code is

```
atribuiImagem() {
  const { atribuiFormState, loadingAtribuiImagens } = this.state;
  const data = {
    id_lote: atribuiFormState.values.batch,
    id_user: atribuiFormState.values.username,
    tipo: atribuiFormState.values.result
  };
  this.setState({ loadingAtribuiImagens: true });
  if (
    data.id_lote !== undefined &&
    data.id_user !== undefined &&
    data.tipo !== undefined
  ) {
    axios
      .post(`${API_URL}/list`, data, getAxiosConfig())
      .then(function() {
        toast.success("Imagem atribuida com sucesso.", toastConfig);
      })
      .catch(function() {
        toast.error("Tente outra vez.", toastConfig);
      });
  } else {
    toast.error("Tente outra vez.", toastConfig);
  }
  this.setState({ atribuiFormState, loadingAtribuiImagens: false });
}
```

then I have a component name Loading

```
const Loading = () => (
  <div className="loading-style text-center">
    <img src={loader} className="loading" alt="Carregando..." />
  </div>
);
```

export default Loading;
I want to make that when the POST request is being send, this Loading component render in the screen for the user, but actually I cant find a way do do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
atribuiImagem = () => {
const { atribuiFormState, loadingAtribuiImagens } = this.state;
const data = {
  id_lote: atribuiFormState.values.batch,
  id_user: atribuiFormState.values.username,
  tipo: atribuiFormState.values.result
};

if(data.id_lote !== undefined && data.id_user !== undefined && data.tipo !== undefined)
 {
 this.setState({ loadingAtribuiImagens: true });
 axios
  .post(`${API_URL}/list`, data, getAxiosConfig())
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ atribuiFormState, loadingAtribuiImagens: false });
    toast.success("Imagem atribuida com sucesso.", toastConfig);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.setState({ atribuiFormState, loadingAtribuiImagens: false });
    toast.error("Tente outra vez.", toastConfig);
  });
 }
else{
  this.setState({ atribuiFormState, loadingAtribuiImagens: false });
  toast.error("Tente outra vez.", toastConfig);
 }      
}
```

Comment: now I'm getting Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: @GuilhermeReisAraujo edited the code, made it => functions.

Comment: worked very well! thank you, I need to know more about => functions

Comment: Sure :  here is a [post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26) about it

Answer (score 0):

As you might be aware set state is async  and also react batches state updates. So if you set loading true and then false immediately your loader would never be displayed. This is what is happening in this piece of code. You set loading to true and then immediately to false.

Move the following line within your .then and .catch

```
this.setState({ loadingAtribuiImagens: false })
```

Also when you are setting state to true move it within your if condition.
So your final code becomes

```
if(/* your condition */) {
    /* set loading to true*/
    /* set loading to false when your promise get resolved or rejected */
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting an error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: @GuilhermeReisAraujo that was because you were not using arrow functions. Arrow function keep  this context same.